# ASP.NET : If logged in to Facebook Fill Form

Tags: facebook, facebook-social-plugins, facebook-authentication

I have a registration form which I want to fill in if user is logged in to facebook. I don't want to use Registration Plugin(http://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/registration/).I want to do it with api.

Thanks .

Answer (score 0):

The facebook terms of use does not allow it's information to be used to autofill forms. I've not personally looked into it's API but I know they do not allow it (At least they didn't a couple of months back).

Comment: It surely can be used else there will be no plugins in market like GigYa.com

Comment: Not the same thing, you can use the facebook registration api, linked to your facebook app, to request info etc. But not use facebook info to autofill nonrelated forms.